# How can I query over a page name at google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, page-views

I am running a website that every customer has a different query string attached to the url plus one random guid attached at the end:

```
/myPage/?cust=one&randomGuid
/myPage/?cust=two&randomGuid
/myPage/?cust=three&randomGuid
```

I would like to measure how many page views I have using only the `cust` query string parameter discarding the random part of the string.

The regex for this job would be `cust=(.*?)&` but I don't know how to apply this in google analytics

Answer (score 2):

You can implement that in Google Analytics with a "search and replace view filter".

- [What filters can do](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en)
- [How to set up and manage filters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=en)
- [An example filter that munges the Request URI](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034834?hl=en) similar to what you want to do.

Basically you want to implement a view filter that removes the random guid.   You would have to write a regular expression to match the guid and replace it with nothing.